# How can I stream audio from server to multiple clients (Node.js) so that the audio sync

Tags: node.js, express, audio, streaming

I am trying to stream my audio from the server in sync to different types of connected users through Nodejs. Only I have no idea where I should start. I have already read and tried different types of stack overflow topics but it never came. At the moment I have this code.

**AudioPlayer class**

```js
class AudioPlayer {
  constructor(stream){
    this.player = new Audio(stream);
    this.player.autoplay = true;
    this.duration = this.player.duration;
  }

  play(){
    let p = this.player;
    if(p.paused) {
      p.play();
    } else {
      p.pause();
      console.log("Paused");
    }
  }

}
```

**Function**

```js
function InitPlayer(token, socket){
  let AudioManager = new AudioPlayer(`/api/${token}`);
  AudioManager.play();
  $("#volumeSlider").bind('change input', () => {
    AudioManager.setVolume()
  });
}
```

We are using the following packages:

- Express
- ytdl-core
- socket.io

**The music is playing well, but the only problem is the synchronisation. We receive a Node.js stream from the package ytdl-core**

Comment: Please explain 'in sync'.  Within 5 sec, or so that phase error at 20kHz is less than 10%?

Comment: I want that if multiple users are connected to the website, they all hear the same thing (like listen music together)